# Grabbing a certain <td> class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to write some code that will, at first, match a player's name with his salary.request.  I was able to write it such that it'll grab each players name from a given team by calling it from the class "sortcell", but I can't seem to figure out how to get the salary because they're all called .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

teams = ['http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/atl/atlanta-hawks']

for team in teams:
    html = urlopen('' + team)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    names = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "sortcell"})
    salary = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "td"})
    print(salary)
    for i in range(1, 15):
        name = names[i].get_text()
        print(name)
```

You can see my (failed) attempt in the code starting with 'salary.'  Any ideas on how to grab just the salary  class?  Thanks!

**Expected Behavior:**

The Salary variable should return the salary for a given player, but currently returns nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `salary` list is empty, because the `<td>` elements with the salary information have no CSS classes; certainly not `td`.

You'd have an easier time if you navigated from the `names` cells to the corresponding salary cell; the last one in the row:

```
for name in soup.find_all("td", class_="sortcell"):
    salary = name.parent.find_all('td')[-1]  # last cell in the row
    print(name.get_text())
    print(salary.get_text())
```

I used the `soup.find_all()` syntax; `findAll()` is the old BeautifulSoup 3 name for the method, which has been deprecated.

Comment: another way of doing this is not to find the `sortcell` td class and then finding the `parent` of it. You can also do something like this `for player in soup.find_all("tr", {"class": re.compile('^player-\d+-\d+')}): print(player.find_all("td")[-1].get_text())`. That's the top-down solution. But Martijn Pieters solution is better, imo.

Comment: Awesome!  Works like a charm, @Martjin! Thank you so much!